# How would I iterate a stack in Java

Tags: java, iterator, stack

I am wondering how to use the iterator in a Stack class. How do I create a iterator class for it?

Comment: public Iterator<Student> iterator() {
  
 }

Answer (score 27):

Just get the `Iterator` via [`iterator()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#iterator%28%29):

```
Stack<YourObject> stack = ...

Iterator<YourObject> iter = stack.iterator();

while (iter.hasNext()){
    System.out.println(iter.next());
}
```

Or alternatively, if you just want to print them all use the [enhanced-for loop](https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/using_enhanced_for_loops_with):

```
for(YourObject obj : stack)
{
    System.out.println(obj);
}
```

Comment: Without iterator - while (!stack.isEmpty()) { ... currentSymbol = stack.pop();...}

Comment: @HiteshSahu After running your code, the `Stack` will be empty as `pop()` removes the top of the stack.

Comment: Agree . I was building a compiler and I was using this variation for syntex parsing.

Comment: There's a bug in the stack iterator, and this approach doesn't return LIFO order.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16992758/is-there-a-bug-in-java-util-stacks-iterator

Answer (score 4):

You could do:

```
for (Iterator<MyObject> iterator = stack.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
   MyObject myObject = iterator.next();
   myObject.doStuff();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you implemented a custom stack class. Your "something" should implement the `Iterable` interface and provide an implementation of `Iterator`.

```
public class MySomethingThatIsAStack<T> implements Iterable<T> {

   @Override
   public Iterator<T> iterator() {
     return new Iterator<T>() {
         // your implementation of the iterator, namely the
         // methods hasNext, next and remove
     }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Stack<Object> myStack; // obtain your Stack object

Iterator iterator = myStack.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
   Object object = iterator.next();
}
```

Comment: Please also write some explanation, what does this code do.

Answer (score 0):

`I am working on something that is implementing a stack using queues`

Does that mean you are not using the Java `Stack` implementation?
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html
It is base on Vector not queues.

If you are using the Java `Stack` implementation, you can use iterator like other answers.
Otherwise, if that's a custom `Stack`, you have to implement the `Iterable` interface. And then you can do something like other answers.