# Is there a bug in java.util.Stack's Iterator?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, stack

Today I was trying to push in `java.util.Stack` class and then use the `Iterator` to iterate (without using pop) through the items. I was expecting LIFO property but got surprised.

Here is the code that I was trying.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Stack;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RobStack<Integer> rstack = new RobStack<Integer>(); // Correct Implementation
        Stack<Integer> jstack = new Stack<Integer>(); // Default Java Implementation
        rstack.push(0); jstack.push(0);
        rstack.push(1); jstack.push(1);
        rstack.push(2); jstack.push(2);
        rstack.push(3); jstack.push(3);

        System.out.print("Algo Stack: ");
        for (int i : rstack)
            System.out.print(i + " ");
        System.out.print("\nJava Stack: ");
        for (int i : jstack)
            System.out.print(i + " ");
    }

}
```

The output the above program is given below:

```
Algo Stack: 3 2 1 0 
Java Stack: 0 1 2 3
```

In the above code `jstack` uses the default Java implementation and `rstack` uses the [implementation provided by Robert Sedgewick](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/13stacks/Stack.java) for his Algorithm class. I found that Prof. Robert's implementation works fine but the `java.util.Stack` implementation fails.

Is it a **bug** or is it by **design**?

Comment: Note: `Stack` is obsolete, you should use a `Deque` instead (for instance an `ArrayDeque`

Comment: And what if you use pop() operation?

Comment: In support of fge's comment, in the doc of [Stack](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) class: `A more complete and consistent set of LIFO stack operations is provided by the Deque interface and its implementations, which should be used in preference to this class.`

Comment: see pop() Returns:
The object at the top of this stack (the last item of the Vector object). the last item , so here u realize that is not the first in the structure inside, so when u iterate u should make a reverse iteration hihi, very bad design

Answer (score 36, accepted):

See [Bug ID 4475301 : RFE: java.util.Stack.iterator() iterates the wrong way](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4475301).  This behavior is by (bad) design. Java's built-in [`Stack`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) iterator methods are inherited from other classes, so they don't behave as you'd expect.

Comment: Why didn't they correct the bug when it can be done by just overriding the Iterator method?

Comment: @vincentmathew Yes, they could have overridden the `iterator()` method just like in Prof. Sedgewick's code that you linked to in order to make it iterate in LIFO order (assuming the same internal representation).

Comment: @BilltheLiazard Maybe they could not have. "It was an incorrect design decision to have Stack extend Vector ("is-a" rather than "has-a"). We sympathize with the submitter but cannot fix this because
of compatibility."

Comment: @vincentmathew Even if they had a different internal representation for the `Stack` (which is probable; I think they use an expanding array approach), they could have come up with some `iterator()` method that iterates in the expected order.  I guess iteration order isn't really a part of the design contract of a stack data structure, but it still seems like a poor choice to me.

Comment: I know this is a very very old thread, but I just wanted to note that they could not invert the iterator, because that would break any code, which accepted a Vector if you gave that method a Stack. Which just goes to show that a Stack is not a vector, and it should not have extended Vector.

Answer (score 14):

You should use Deque instead of Stack.

```
Deque<Integer> stack = new ArrayDeque<Integer>();
```

[See Oracle Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html)

Answer (score 3):

Well by principle, you should not iterate over a `Stack`, but only push on top or pop from top. As for actual implementation, most languages, including Java, use another `collection type` to implement a `Stack`. From strict requirements point of view, it should allow constant time `push, top and pop` operation.

Any additional features (or bug in this case), should just be ignored and not relied upon for coding.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps, you can use .get() to print items within stack from top to bottom.

```
Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<Integer>();
stack.push(3);
stack.push(2);
stack.push(1);
// print from top to bottom
for(int i = stack.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--){
   System.out.println(stack.get(i));
}
/*
output
1
2
3
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

[Eclipse Collections](http://www.eclipse.org/collections/) includes a [mutable stack implementation](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse-collections/blob/master/eclipse-collections-api/src/main/java/org/eclipse/collections/api/stack/MutableStack.java) where the iterator returns values from top to bottom. This code prints 3, 2, then 1.

```
MutableStack<Integer> stack = ArrayStack.newStack();
stack.push(1);
stack.push(2);
stack.push(3);
for (Iterator<Integer> iterator = stack.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); )
{
    Integer each = iterator.next();
    System.out.println(each);
}
```

`MutableStack` does not extend `MutableCollection` or `Collection`, so that you can't remove from the middle of the stack, for example. Methods that implement internal iteration patterns like `forEach()`, `select()`, `collect()`, `anySatisfy()`, `allSatisfy()`, etc. also process elements from top to bottom. This code prints the same thing.

```
stack.forEach(Procedures.println(System.out));
```

**Note:** I am a committer for Eclipse collections.

Answer (score 1):

Stack inherits *.listIterator()* from *AbstractList* which allows inverse order iteration.

```
Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<Integer>();
stack.push(1);
stack.push(2);
stack.push(3);
for (ListIterator<Integer> iterator = stack.listIterator(stack.size()); iterator.hasPrevious();) {
    Integer integer = iterator.previous();
    System.out.println(integer);
}
// Output: 3 2 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a `Stack` you can use a `LinkedList` and use the [`push`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#push(E)) and [`pop`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#pop()) methods.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a stack implementation with built-in reverse order iteration.

```java
public class PowerStack<T> implements Iterable {
    private List<T> items = new ArrayList<T>();
    
    void push(T item) {
        items.add(item);
    }
    
    void pop() {
        this.items.remove(this.topElementIndex());
    }
    
    T top() {
        return items.get(this.topElementIndex());
    }
    
    private int topElementIndex() {
        return items.size() - 1;
    }
        
    @Override
    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        return new ReverseOrderIterator<T>(items);
    }
}

public class ReverseOrderIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {
    private List<T> items;
    private int index;
    
    public ReverseOrderIterator(List<T> items) {
        this.items = items;
        this.index = items.size() - 1;
    }
    
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return this.index > 0;
    }
    
    public T next() {
        return this.items.get(index--);
    }
}
```